# Closure function with Lottie Animation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, closures, lottie

Is there a way to know when an `Lottie animation` is finished? I need to `delete`  a `tableViewCell`  but only AFTER the `animation`  is finished. This is the `animation`:

**Setup:**

```
    //MARK: setup Loading-Animation
func setupLoadingAnimation(){

    successAnimation.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.contentView.addSubview(successAnimation)

    successAnimation.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
    successAnimation.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    successAnimation.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160).isActive = true
    successAnimation.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160).isActive = true

    successAnimation.isHidden = true
    successAnimation.loopMode = .playOnce
}
```

**Action:**

```
@objc func checkButtonTapped(){
    self.deleteWishCallback?()
    self.successAnimation.isHidden = false
    self.successAnimation.play()
}
```

What I would like to achieve is to be able to call `self.deleteWishCallback?()`  in the closure  of `self.successAnimation.play()`. Is there a way to get this done ? Couldnt find anything on this!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Lottie Animation Basic Playing**

```
AnimationView.play(completion: LottieCompletionBlock?)
```

Plays the animation from its current state to the end of its timeline. Calls the completion block when the animation is stopped.

Parameters: : completion: A completion block that is called when the animation completes. The block will be passed **true** if the animation completes and **false** if the animation was interrupted. Optional.

Example:

```
starAnimationView.play { (finished) in
      // Animation finished
      //here if finised is true you can perform the action of deleting the tableviewCell
    }
```

You can find more [HERE](https://airbnb.io/lottie/#/ios?id=enabling-and-disabling-animation-nodes)